# How to make TapGestureRecognizer work by clickin an image in xamarin 2019?

Tags: xaml, xamarin.android

I have this code in my xaml:

```
<Image Source="Record"
 WidthRequest ="200"
 HeightRequest="158">

   <Image.GestureRecognizers>
      <TapGestureRecognizer x:Name="ImgRecord"
                            Tapped="ImgRecord_Tapped"
                            NumberOfTapsRequired="1"/>
   </Image.GestureRecognizers>

</Image>
```

This in my cs:

```
        private async void ImgRecord_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {
                //Code to execute on tapped event
                await Navigation.PushAsync(new Record());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }

        }
```

its giving me an error 
System.FormatException Message=One of the identified items was in an invalid format.

When I click the img I need to be redirected to another page.

Comment: I think its because you are giving a name to `TapGestureRecognizor` basically remove `x:Name="ImgRecord"`

Comment: it still throws me the same error :(

Comment: Can you show me the code for your Page!!!

Comment: that is my code, the one that I posted, I am new in xamarin. maybe I need to update something? my nuget is all updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> its giving me an error System.FormatException Message=One of the identified items was in an invalid format.

Because you don't give correct image source format for image. The image source should like a.png,b.jpg etc. Please modify your image source, I use the following code and don't find any issue.

```
  <Image
            HeightRequest="158"
            Source="check.png"
            WidthRequest="200">

            <Image.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer
                    x:Name="ImgRecord"
                    NumberOfTapsRequired="1"
                    Tapped="ImgRecord_Tapped" />
            </Image.GestureRecognizers>

        </Image>
```

Here is the image article that you can take a look:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/images?tabs=windows

The screenshot:

[image]

Comment: @Hacki, Have you modified Image source? If yes, you still have the same issue, can you provide one sample at github that can reproduce your issue and share your link here, I will test your sample at my side.You can take a look my screenshot, it works fine.

Comment: I do not think it is mandatory to give image extension if the image is in the resources!

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT the one that I posted is literally my code

Comment: @FreakyAli where do I properly place my images in the resources? I created a folder and placed it inside resources, inside that folder Resources->Myfolder, I placed all my images there

Comment: No, you need to keep it in your Native Android's Resources folder under drawable.

Comment: the images should be in proj_name.Android->Resources->Drawable?

Comment: @Hacki, Yes, you need to place images in the **project.android/ Resources/drawable** directory with **Build Action: AndroidResource**. But if you have **error message :The system  can not find the path specified** when adding image in Drawable folder, you can right-click Resources folder to choose Open Folder in File explorer, then you can see there is not drawable folder, so you should create drawable folder in this resources folder, then you can add image in drawable folder. More detailed info about adding image, please take a look the article my provided.

Comment: @Hacki, Anything updating? If my reply help you, please remember to mark my reply as answer, thanks.

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT I tried ur code, but still not working well, I re installed my vs2019, and it works, I dont know why, Thank you for your help :D :D